GET works but all other requests give "API Gateway : Internal Server Error"
I saw the answers to a similar question here. But it didn't help with my issue
When I do a GET request on Postman I get my "GET TEST" response but when I do any other type of request I get "API Gateway : Internal server error"
I have my resource set up with the various method types
I have a lambda function with the following code (I removed cursor / db credential code):
import json
import mysql.connector

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    http_method = event.get('httpMethod')
    response = None  
    
    if http_method == "GET":
        response = getFunction(cursor, event)
    elif http_method == "POST":
         response = postFunction(cursor, event) 
    elif http_method == "PUT":
         response = putFunction(cursor, event)
    elif http_method == "DELETE":
         response = deleteFunction(cursor, event) 
        
  
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "event": event,
            "response": response
        })
    }

def getFunction(cursor, event):
    return "GET TEST"
    
def postFunction():
    return "POST TEST"
    
def putFunction():
    return "PUT TEST"

def deleteFunction():
    return "DELETE TEST"


Oh man I'm a noob.
I looked at the Cloudwatch logs and realized I didn't have arguments for my functions.
def getFunction(cursor, event):
    return "GET TEST"
    
def postFunction(cursor, event):     #I was missing arguments/parameters here
    return "POST TEST"
    
def putFunction():
    return "PUT TEST"


I am building an APP that goes React -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> AWS Services. The only advice I can suggest to others reading this is to test your Lambda function, test your API Gateway endpoint, make sure you are passing the correct data ( - ie JSON) and you ensure Lambda/ API Gateway is returning the result set you expect. There is a lot of little details to cover

It would be best if you showed the corrected code in the answer.
